# How to upload images from multiple imageviews to firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

I'm making app for a gas station , and need to add the image feature for every category, now because there are 20 categories, it would be complicated to make a method for every separated category , is there specific method to upload all the images at the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing specific for uploading multiple images. You should just call the API for [uploading a single file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files) for each of the files you want to upload.